# iOS press and hold gesture + tap

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have a press and hold gesture. During the the press and hold, I'd like to detect single taps elsewhere on the screen. The problem is that when I start tapping elsewhere on the screen the press and hold gesture is interrupted and does not call the "touch up" function. Is there a way to retain the press and hold while tapping elsewhere?

Comment: Does "elswhere on the screen" mean on different views or in the same view? From the symptoms you're describing it looks like it's the same UIView with several (at least 2) UIGesture recognizers. Is that correct?

Comment: Same view. And you are correct. It has multiple gestures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIKit provides several mechanisms to make multiple `UIGestureRecognizers`
on the same `UIView` work side by side. Which ones and how exactly depends
on your needs and configuration.

One is `- (void)requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`

However for your case you'll have to adopt `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol in your view.

Then you should implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` method.

For example:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer 
{
    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to make your `UIView` a `delegate` of it's `getureRecognizers`.

Some references:

[UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[UIGestureRecognizerDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

[Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541)