# shoot projectiles while button is held

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

What I want to do in my game is so that projectiles are being constantly shot while the Shoot button is held. What I've been using is a simple touchesBegan and touchesMoved (which just calls touchesBegan) solutions. So the problem I encountered is: you only shoot once if you hold the button, but if you move the touch point (which calls the touchesMoved method) just a bit while holding it, you WILL shoot multiple projectiles at a time.

What I need help with: how to keep constantly shooting these projectiles while the button is being held, as you would do in a Touch Down sort of method? Hope what I have requested is possible.

Comment: post your current implementation so that we can help improve it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elegant way to implement press and hold continuous event firing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248889/elegant-way-to-implement-press-and-hold-continuous-event-firing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` function to keep track of how long the button was pressed. Then use the `update` function of the `SKScene` to shoot projectiles with a delay.

The logic is to set a boolean `shooting` to true when the button is pressed. `shooting` is set to false inside `touchesEnded`. This way we can keep track of the touch. Then in the `update` function the projectiles are shot if the `shooting` variable is true.

In Objective C

```
//GameScene.h

@property (nonatomic,strong) SKSpriteNode *shootButton;

//GameScene.m

BOOL shooting = false;
CFTimeInterval lastShootingTime = 0;
CFTimeInterval delayBetweenShots = 0.5;

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    if  ([self nodeAtPoint:location] == self.shootButton)
    {
        shooting = true;
        NSLog(@"start shooting");
    }

}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    if  ([self nodeAtPoint:location] == self.shootButton)
    {
        shooting = false;
        NSLog(@"stop shooting");
    }
}


-(void)shoot
{
    // Projectile code
    NSLog(@"shooting");
}

-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

    if (shooting)
    {
        NSTimeInterval delay = currentTime - lastShootingTime;
        if (delay >= delayBetweenShots) {
            [self shoot];
            lastShootingTime = currentTime;
        }
    }
}
```

In Swift

```
var shootButton : SKSpriteNode!

var shooting = false
var lastShootingTime : CFTimeInterval = 0
var delayBetweenShots : CFTimeInterval = 0.5

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch: AnyObject? = touches.anyObject()
    if let location = touch?.locationInNode(self)
    {
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == shootButton
        {
            self.shooting = true
            println("start shooting")
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch: AnyObject? = touches.anyObject()
    if let location = touch?.locationInNode(self)
    {
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == shootButton
        {
            self.shooting = false
            println("stop shooting")
        }
    }
}

func shoot()
{
    // Projectile code
    println("shooting")
}

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    if shooting
    {
        let delay = currentTime - lastShootingTime
        if delay >= delayBetweenShots {
            shoot()
            lastShootingTime = currentTime
        }
    }
}
```

You can adjust the `delayBetweenShots` variable to change how fast the firing needs to happen.

Comment: I somewhat understood this Swift code though knowing little about it and implemented it in Objective-C, but noticed that you can bypass the limit by QUICKLY TAPPING the button instead of HOLDING it. This isn't what I want — how can I inspect that, too?

Comment: Try removing the lastshootingtime = -1 from touchesBegan